# Good libdbus Tutorials in C? More specifically the introspection part?

Tags: programming, dbus

I've been looking around for tutorials on libdbus, and wanting to learn about it. I'm mostly getting stuck on the Introspection parts and where my Methods, Interfaces, and Signals will end up. There are not very many good tutorials about it and I find it very confusing.

I'd also like to see the Methods, signals, appear in D-feet, so I know what I'm doing.

This is mostly experimentation.

Comment: Suggestion: Try some of the Python D-bus tools. The Methods and Interfaces will become clearer that way. Then you can convert to C a bit more easily.

Comment: @user535733 that would be a great idea. What tools and good tutorials would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a high-level library like https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd-bus.html if you like to interact with dbus in C.
Or use high-level tools like busctl

Comment: The issue with that is, the application needs to be systemd independent

Comment: Not only that, but it needs to avoid GTK and QT dependencies too